# Mapping F1 key to trigger action

Tags: jquery

Trying to map F1 key to trigger button action

By checking here:
https://www.toptal.com/developers/keycode

F1 key has code 112

Tried

```
$(document).keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 112) {
        $("#next action-button").click();
    }
});
```

But it opens Chrome Help page.

Comment: Use `.on("keydown"` and you need to cancel the event too:  `$(document).on("keydown", (e) => { if (e.key === "F1") { e.preventDefault(); $("#next action-button").click(); }); });`

Comment: Worked, please write it as an answer

Comment: Not necessary. It was an easily found dupe.